# cell stored as var using tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) is changing (iOS)

Tags: ios

I'm using a longPress gesture recognizer to rearrange cells by creating a  snapshot of the cell and detecting the snapshot's Y position, and rearranging the table accordingly when the long press ends.  Everything works great.

One issue however,  is that when I scroll down off the screen, the cell that I stored with `tableView.cellForRow(at:` method seems to change.  I know this is because the cell is being dequeued b/c it is a reusuable cell, but how do I create a reference to this which doesnt change?

```
fileprivate var cellBeingMoved: MediaCell?  //var that is changing

func longPressGestureRecognized(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
     switch state {
         case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
             if indexPath != nil {
                 if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as? MediaCell {              

                     //This variable is changing when the cell goes off the screen
                     self.cellBeingMoved = cell

                     self.createScreenshotOfCell(cell)
                 }
             }

         case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
              //detect Y position
         default:
              //rearrange table, 
     }
}
```

Comment: Store the index path and use that to get the cell when you need it, don't store the cell.

Comment: Ah, good idea, i'll try that.

Comment: That was the answer, thanks